# Date validation function scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, date

I have RDD[(String, String)]. String contains datetimestamp in format ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"). I am converting it in epoch time using the below function where dateFormats is SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

```
def epochTime (stringOfTime: String): Long = dateFormats.parse(stringOfTime).getTime
```

I want to modify the function so as to delete the row if it contains null/empty/not-right formatted date and how to apply it to the RDD[(String, String)] so the string value get converted to epoch time as below

Input

(2020-10-10 05:17:12,2015-04-10 09:18:20)

(2020-10-12 06:15:58,2015-04-10 09:17:42)

(2020-10-11 07:16:40,2015-04-10 09:17:49)

Output

(1602303432,1428653900)

(1602479758,1428653862)

(1602397000,1428653869)

Comment: Make your function return an optional instance of Long value, and filter the rows that when applied to this function, would have a `Some` value.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a filter to determine which value is not None. To do this you need to change the epochTime method so that it can return Option[Long],`def epochTime (stringOfTime: String): Option[Long]` inside your method make a check to see if the string is null with the [.nonEmpty](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/StringOps.html#nonEmpty:Boolean) method, then you can use [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/util/Try.html) to see if you can parse the string with dateFormats.

After these changes, you must filter the RDD to remove None, and then unwrap each value from Option to Long

The code itself:

```
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Data Validation")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val data = Seq(("2020-10-10 05:17:12","2015-04-10 09:18:20"), ("2020-10-12 06:15:58","2015-04-10 09:17:42"),
      ("2020-10-11 07:16:40","2015-04-10 09:17:49"), ("t", "t"))

    val rdd:RDD[(String,String)] = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

    def epochTime (stringOfTime: String): Option[Long] = {
      val dateFormats = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      if (stringOfTime.nonEmpty) {
        val parseDate = Try(dateFormats.parse(stringOfTime).getTime)
        parseDate match {
          case Success(value) => Some(value)
          case _ => None
        }
      } else {
        None
      }
    }
    rdd.map(pair => (epochTime(pair._1),epochTime(pair._2)))
      .filter(pair => pair._1.isDefined && pair._2.isDefined)
      .map(pair => (pair._1.get, pair._2.get))
      .foreach(pair => println(s"Results: (${pair._1}, ${pair._2})"))}
```